# Help with multidimensional Arrays in PHP

Tags: php, arrays, multidimensional-array, key

How can I get the key and the value ? I tried using key() but it didn't work:

```
$array_newbie = array();
$array_newbie['121412'] = "Hello";
$array_newbie['121212'] = "Noob";
$array_newbie['155161'] = "nabbaa";
foreach($array_newbie as $k)
{
echo key($array_newbie) . "\n";
}
```

this outputs:

```
121212
121212
121212
```

how can I get the key value ? I want it to output

```
121412
121212
155161
```

i'm new to php and having trouble with this multi dimensional arrays, thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`key()` is getting the key of the current array pointer. In your case, it is always `0`.

You can get it via the `foreach`.

```
foreach($array_newbie as $key => $k) {
    echo $key . "\n";
}
```

Also, that array is an *associative array*, **not** a *multi-dimensional array*.

The latter is an array of whom their members are also arrays...

```
$arr = array(
   array(
      'a', 'b', 'c'
   ),
   array(
      'd', 'e', 'f'
   )
);
```

Comment: got it, thank you very much, another quick question: How can I remove everything before a word in a string ? example: I have this: colegas-que-manjam-de-harry-potter_t_1578519 and I want this: 1578519, removing everything before _t_ and _t_

Comment: @AndréCardoso: That is really a new question in itself. Ask it and link me :)

Comment: Heh, thank you very much, I will link you in 13 minutes ( time till I can post another question, lol )